# Differentiation with respect to complex matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices

I want to differentiate $f(X,Y) = \Vert XYA-b \Vert^2_2 $ with respect to $X$ and $Y$, $X$ and $Y$ are matrices with complex variable elements. In real cases, I know how to differentiate there is online tools such as http://www.matrixcalculus.org/#example-collapse7 ,But, I do not know how much differences exist between complex and real cases?

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\bb{\mathbb}
\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
$Denote the transpose, complex, and hermitian conjugates of $X$ as $(X^T,X^*,X^H)$ respectively. And denote the trace/Frobenius product using a colon
$$A:B = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}B_{ij} \;\doteq\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
This product is also defined for vectors by considering them as rectangular matrices. The cyclic property of the trace permits terms in such a product to be rearranged in many equivalent ways. For example
$$\eqalign{
&A:BC = B^TA:C = AC^T:B = I:A^TBC = I:BCA^T \\
&B:C = B^T:C^T = C:B = C^T:B^T \\
}$$
A useful guide is that the quantity on either side of the colon must have exactly the same dimensions.

The Frobenius norm of $X$ can be written using the Frobenius product as
$$\big\|X\big\|^2_F = X^*:X$$
The last tool is the $\bb{CR}$-calculus
(aka Wirtinger derivatives), wherein the real and imaginary components of a variable are treated independently under differentiation.

Write the function using the above ideas, and calculate its real Wirtinger derivative.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= (XYA-B)^*:(XYA-B) \\
df &= (XYA-B)^*:dX\,YA \\
   &= (XYA-B)^*A^TY^T:dX \\
\p{f}{X} &= (XYA-B)^*A^TY^T \\
}$$
Analogous calculations yield the gradient wrt the *complex* component of $X$
$$\eqalign{
\p{f}{X^*}   &= (XYA-B)A^HY^H \\
}$$
and wrt the components of $Y$
$$\eqalign{
\p{f}{Y}   &= X^T(XYA-B)^*A^T \\
\p{f}{Y^*} &= X^H(XYA-B)A^H \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you. It seems that complex and real matrix derivative have difference.